# Need to add rel attribute to url output by essential grid plugin for WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So, after many hours of trying to get this working (and being tempted to just give up and light myself on fire) I've decided the best thing to do is ask the mega minds that hang here on stackoverflow.

Now, here's what I've been trying to accomplish. I need to append/inject the rel attribute to the links in the Essential Grid plugin for WordPress. I've opened a ticket with ThemePunch (the plugin author) and their response was to copy (and edit accordingly) the snippet of code below which, if done correctly, would append the  tags with the (in my case) rel="m_PageScroll2id". I've tried all sorts or selectors (classes, #'s, etc) and no matter what I do, I never see the rel="m_PageScroll2id" being added to anything anywhere in Firebug or Chrome Inspector. So, anyhoo, I've pasted my lastest jQuery failure below as well as a link to the page containing the Essential Grid.

The instance of Essential Grid is directly below the homepage slider and contains 6 grid items. Also, just so you guys can see what I need to make happen, I also set up an item in the site's main nav called 'TEST'. If you inspect that link, you'll see the rel="m_PageScroll2id" that I need to happen on links in Essential Grid.

I'm adding the code in the Custom JS panel in Ess Grid.

```
`$(function() { 
  $('.welcome a').attr('rel', 'm_PageScroll2id');
});`
```

And here's a link to the page in question: http://wclatlanta.wpengine.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watch on your site, dev-console said `$ is not a function`. But `jQuery` - is a function in the same place. Replace

```
$(function() { 
   $('.welcome a').attr('rel', 'm_PageScroll2id');
});
```

with

```
jQuery(function() { 
   jQuery('.welcome a').attr('rel', 'm_PageScroll2id');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! MysterX, I really appreciate you sharing your knowledge and helping me get this working! I pasted the code in that you graciously provided and it started working IMMEDIATELY! You just saved my day!